i have problems with combining highchart sunburst with highchart dashboard
I cannot design the sunburst in the dashboard. I tried to switch off styledMode ...but nothing
It look like Highchart Dashboard ignore the setting styledMode. Is ist possible to start Highchart Dashboard without styledmode ?
outside of Dashboard it looks like this
enter image description here
inside Dashboard:
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In Highcharts Dashboards, styled mode is enabled by default. Unfortunately, you can't disable styled mode for Highcharts Dashboards as a whole.
However, you can customize the styles by overriding the default CSS. You can create your own CSS rules to style the components as per your requirements.
Start with importing the default CSS stylesheets​:
@import url("https://code.highcharts.com/dashboards/css/dashboards.css");
@import url("https://code.highcharts.com/dashboards/css/datagrid.css");

Then you can add your own CSS rules to customize the appearance of the sunburst chart or any other component. For example:
.highcharts-series {
  fill: #ff0000; /* Example: Change series fill color */
}

